# Why can't people just pump water from ground and flood deserts to make them habitable?

Tags: water

I know this may be the wrong site, but I'm a curious man and I want to solve world's problems.

One of big problems is deserts. They're so dry that nothing grows there.

I was thinking about this and why can't people just install pumps that flood the deserts and keep flooding them nonstop until they recede and the land turns into habitable and green land with grass? Then plant trees, etc?

Just install tons of pumps and pump 24/7. And then install pipes to get water further into desert. Add tons of sprinklers everywhere.

Why isn't anyone doing this??

Comment: Maybe... [earthscience.se] would be a better place for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terraforming a desert and not physics.

Comment: Especially in desert regions, water is a valuable commodity.   Much of the water would run-off or quickly evaporate.   It's better to retain water with the right kind of plants and soil than to use it liberally, especially when ground water is finite.  Here's a story about that approach.  http://www.ipsnews.net/2011/10/africa-the-man-who-stopped-the-desert/ - good question though, not a physics question, but it's a good question.

Comment: Bit of a sidebar, but if it was possible to pump water from deep up to the roots of plants, but not all the way to the surface, that just might work, but such a system would be complicated and expensive to build.   You'd need less water if you applied the water directly to the roots of plants a few feet below the surface and unused water would trickle back down.

Comment: The phrase "dry hole" is rather important here.

Answer (score 9):

We already do this - that's how food is grown in so many parts of the world where historically a desert or very arid biome has existed.

There are a few problems with this approach. In the desert, there are two main ways you can get fresh water.  You can pump it up from aquifers, or you can get it from the ocean and desalinate it.  The main disadvantage of desalination is that it is extremely energy-intensive. I haven't calculated anything, but I think desalinating enough water to green the desert would require a civilization-size energy source.  Therefore we'll focus on the aquifer solution.

The primary problem with pumping massive amount of water out of an aquifer is that **there's a finite amount of water in an aquifer**. If you take water out of an aquifer faster than it is being replenished naturally, then eventually the aquifer will run out of water!  That's basic math - take more out than you put in and the amount will decrease.

Long before you actually run out of water, you run into other problems - for instance, as you pump water out of an aquifer, the level drops! That means you need to drill ever deeper wells to even get to the water.  In addition, when you lower the water level in an aquifer, it can allow seawater to seep in from bordering oceans. If this process continues, you may end up with a contaminated and salinated aquifer; even if the water isn't gone, it isn't usable any more.

There's also an issue that deserts aren't very good at absorbing water - if you just pump water onto the surface of the desert, most of it will just evaporate. You need soil and pre-existing plants to absorb and hold water.

Finally, I would point out that many deserts are rich ecosystems full of specially adapted organisms. Just because people can't live there or farm there well doesn't meant that they aren't living ecosystems that deserve study and protection. Turning deserts into grassland or farmland might seem attractive, but a lot would be lost in the process.

Irrigating arid land is already being done in many areas. For example, aquifers in the west and central parts of the USA are being severely depleted by irrigation - farmers pump water up and onto the land, creating arable land where there was none before.  Much agriculture in North Africa is made possible by pumping water out of the Nubian aquifer.

This is all not to say that in some cases de-desertification is impossible! To do it sustainably would require a more complicated approach than simply pumping all the groundwater onto the surface.

---

Epilogue:

I did run into something interesting when looking into this. The largest aquifer system in the world, the [Nubian Aquifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nubian_Sandstone_Aquifer_System) lies beneath parts of North Africa. The amount of water estimated to lie in the aquifer is around 36,000 cubic miles. If you wanted to drop the same amount of water on the Sahara desert (which has an area of 3.6 million square miles) as gets dropped naturally via precipitation in a grassland (roughly 150 cm), you would only need around 3,000 cubic miles.  That means you actually have enough water to artificially create grassland-intensity precipitation for 12 years before the aquifer is dry!

Unfortunately, in the process, you would deprive the many people and animals that depend on the aquifer of water - and not just for a little while. The aquifer isn't recharged much in the desert areas - it's recharged in mountainous areas, and the water has to seep through the bedrock at speeds ranging from nanometers to millimeters per second.  It would take many lifetimes for the aquifer to recharge!  In the process, seawater would be drawn even further inland under the bedrock, meaning anyone living in those areas would be lacking fresh groundwater for a long time!

Comment: +1 for thoroughness, +1 for being concise, -1 because it's not physics... ha ha

Comment: @Asher Well 2/3 ain't bad.

Answer (score -2):

If you pump out ground water faster than it is replenished, it will be depleted, sooner or later (http://water.usgs.gov/edu/gwdepletion.html )

Comment: This doesn't deserve to be posted as an answer: It should be a comment.

Comment: @Danu: This is just your opinion. According to the rules, "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" (physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer )

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @John Rennie: The question is "Why can't people just pump water from ground and flood deserts to make them habitable?" I provided an answer: the amount of ground water is limited. So I am not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @akhmeteli: I haven't downvoted, but I thought this was a comment rather than an answer. An answer would have to be considerably more quantitative.

Comment: @John Rennie: Again, this is an opinion. Apparently, your standards are higher than mine. I decide what is an answer and what is a comment based on the rule of this site (I quoted it above in a reply to Danu's comment). I am sure you can have the rule amended, then I would have to follow the new rule. However, I am not sure I (and probably some other people here) would write "considerably more quantitative" answers, I would probably write much fewer answers. I don't think answers must be "all or nothing". If you believe the site needs higher standards, you should have the rule changed.